# Error 401 while extracting using python tweepy

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I am using Twitter API.

I am getting an error while I am running this code; it prints 401 at each line like this: [image: (see this)]

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"

consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY"
consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:
    stream.filter(track=['python'])
```

I have entered my access token and consumer key generated by the help of Twitter.
What am I doing wrong?